# can't switch between ui-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $scope.tabs to control two tabs within my browser window

```
$scope.tabs = [
  {heading: 'Setup', active: true, disabled: false},
  {heading: 'Editor', active: false, disabled: true},
]
```

when the user clicks a button I'm calling a continue function which should enable the second tab and switch to it

```
$scope.continue = function () {
  $scope.tabs[1].disabled = false;
  $scope.tabs[1].active = true;
}
```

However when I click the button the tab is enabled but doesn't show in the browser. If I click a second time then the tab becomes visible. I've tried setting tabs[0] active to false
before activating tabs[1] but this leads to a blank space with neither tab visible.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Comment: please post in Fiddle your code: http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/710/. And post your HTML as well

Comment: code posted, not sure how to attach ui-bootstrap as dependency

Comment: its ok, post the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/714/

Comment: posted answer, see below

Answer (score 2):

Here we go:

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbPSuAXmhuKLVCKIuezX?p=preview)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

 <a href="" ng-click="continue()">click me</a>

<tabset >
        <tab ng-repeat="tabItem in tabs" 
        heading="{{tabItem.heading}}"
        active="tabItem.active"
        disabled="tabItem.disabled"
        >
            {{tabItem.content}}
        </tab>

    </tabset>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

   myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.tabs = [
        {heading: 'Setup', active: true, disabled: false, content: "This is Setup"},
        {heading: 'Editor', active: false, disabled: true, content: "This is Editor"}        
    ];

    $scope.continue = function () {
      // just to switch flags
      $scope.tabs[0].disabled = !$scope.tabs[0].disabled; 
      $scope.tabs[0].active = !$scope.tabs[0].active;

      $scope.tabs[1].disabled = !$scope.tabs[1].disabled;  
      $scope.tabs[1].active = !$scope.tabs[1].active;
    };

  });
```

Comment: The original code I posted would also work in this example. I tried your amendment but still no change. Maybe its a slight bug. I'm using angular-bootstrap 0.4.0. I'm gonna try 0.6 to see if that fixes it

Comment: yeah if you change the script to src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" in your plunker demo you can see the bug replicated

Comment: sorry i mean src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"

Comment: please change my demo and post plunker link

Comment: `active` doesn't change, see Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mADFKtp8SiFNrAhm6vvJ?p=preview